# Sample Size Needed based on type of analysis

Tags: anova, sample-size, statistical-power

I want to run an ANOVA identifying what features they've used in the last 7 days (based on predefined list) and based on the 10 features listed as using, ask them their satisfaction rating. I plan to do 4 subgroups looking at 2 age groups and by 2 locations .

So some participants will be in more multiple groups based on the number of features they've used - meaning different sample sizes in each future group. I've seen power analysis and sample size calculator online to determine appropriate sample size, but I'm not sure what the ideal option.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What are you hoping to learn??

Comment: I'm hoping to learn if there is a significant difference between satisfaction across 10 different features and see if age and location affects satisfaction levels. And given not everyone I survey will use all 10 features, there will be some feature levels that has more respondents than others.